# how do i convert semicode to sql

Tags: sql, loops

i want convert semicod as we can see below to sql in toad
can you help me please
thanks for your attention

```
declare flag int 
for branch_1 to branch_N
 flag=0
  for lower_bound to upper_bound  
   if flag <3
    for i=1 to 3
     if lower_bound = lower_bound +1  not in temp table
       flag=flag+1
     end if
    end for

 end if
end for
end for
```

Comment: This pseudo code is hard to understand - or is that just me ;-) What are branch_1 and branch_n? Rows in a branch table? What are lower_bound and upper_bound? Values stored in a branch table row? What does `if lower_bound = lower_bound +1  not in temp table` mean? Are these supposed to be two code lines that got mixed up?

Comment: To describe a problem with loops and counters and flags is very uncommon for SQL tasks. SQL is a fourth generation language, the strength of which is to come close to human language. So, can't you just describe what you want in words? Something along the lines of "I want to show all branches from the branch table, each with a counter of how many related entries it has in table xy". It is also a good idea to show sample data and the expected result, so people get an idea of what you are after.